# Send email from draft folder

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

with the below VBA coding, I am able to send all the emails from outlook draft folder but the only problem is that I have to provide the parent folder name.  Can we get this details through coding as this macro will be used by other user who is not familiar with VBA.

```
Dim lDraftItem As Long
Dim myOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myFolders As Outlook.Folders
Dim myDraftsFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set myOutlook = Outlook.Application
Set myNameSpace = myOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolders = myNameSpace.Folders
Set myDraftsFolder = myFolders("Gaus_Shaikh2@syntelinc.com").Folders("Drafts")

For lDraftItem = myDraftsFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1

    If Len(Trim(myDraftsFolder.Items.Item(lDraftItem).To)) > 0 Then
        myDraftsFolder.Items.Item(lDraftItem).Send

    End If

Next lDraftItem
```

Comment: What you mean parent folder name? myFolders?

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
Set myDraftsFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)
```

*** Edit ***

The code below is probably a better function to use; it has error checking incorporated so any e-mails with invalid fields in the 'To' section shouldn't abort the function

```
Sub TestSendDrafts()
    Call SendDraftMail
End Sub

Function SendDraftMail() As Boolean
On Error GoTo ExitFunction
    Dim ThisNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace: Set ThisNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim DraftFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set DraftFolder = ThisNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)

    Dim Var As Variant, i As Long, Difference As Long, SentItems As Long
    For i = DraftFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Var = DraftFolder.Items.Item(i)
        DoEvents
        If Var.Class = olMail Then
            If Len(Trim(Var.To)) > 0 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Var.Send
                If Err.Number = 0 Then SentItems = SentItems + 1
                On Error GoTo ExitFunction
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    Debug.Print "Sent " & SentItems & " message(s) from 'Draft E-mail'."
    SendDraftMail = True

ExitFunction:
End Function
```

Comment: I used it but now getting error at code myDraftsFolder.Items.Item(lDraftItem).send

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
Set myDraftsFolder = myFolders("Gaus_Shaikh2@syntelinc.com").Folders("Drafts")
```

With these three lines:

```
Dim sUser As String
sUser = myFolders.Item(2).Name

Set myDraftsFolder = myFolders(sUser).Folders("Drafts")
```

The 2nd folder name will be the user account name (e-mail address), which you can store as a string and pass into `myFolders()` to qualify their specific account.

Comment: It provide me the sUser value as "Public Folders - Gaus_Shaikh2@syntelinc.com". I removed the "Public Folder - " using replace function but now it is throwing an error as " This method  can't be used with an inline  response mail item"

Comment: Make sure the `sUser` value is the exact name of your actual Folder. Also, you can iterate through the items `1, 2, 3` to test which one returns email only.

Comment: I am getting error at myDraftsFolder.Items.Item(lDraftItem).send

Comment: @Gaus - That is a separate question. If one of the answers here helped you, please mark it as answered and post the other question (which is out of the scope of this question) as a new question.